# NHibernate and DTOs to return specific data from hierarchical data

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dto, resulttransformer

I have several tables that I need to pull data from but I do not need all of the data in all of the tables. So for example I have the following Order object that contains several child objects and object collections.

```
 public class Order
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Coupon CouponID { get; set; }  
    public virtual Status StatusID { get; set; }
    public virtual Address ShippingAddressID { get; set; }
    public virtual Address BillingAddressID { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<OrderShipmentHistory> OrdertHistories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderShipmentNote> OrderNotes { get; set; }      
    public virtual ShippingDetails ShippingDetail { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderProduct> OrderProducts { get; set; }
}
```

Also some of these child objects in turn have child objects and at the most extreme we have a 4 tier object hierarchy.

So my problem is that I need to retrieve a list of objects that contain only specific information from most of these child objects.

Currently when I retrieve the list of orders I am pulling everything back. I have used lazy loading so that I don't do this but I will eventually need to pull this information back as I am accessing at least one piece of data in each of these child objects.

So I was thinking that instead of populating a list of orders I could create DTO's for each of the data collections that I need. My problem is I am not sure where to start. I have seen examples of people using DTO's but are only populating them once they have retrieved all of the data. I don't want to do this. I want to only retrieve the data I need and then populate the DTO's with the result sets.

I would really appreciate any guidance on where I should start and what I should be using.

regards

Noel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is called projection.

To project your object graph to a flattened structure use for example linq select.

Now within the select you can either directly create the data strongly typed with your Dto or just return an `IEnumerable<T>` where T is dynamic or some other Poco and pass this around...

Simple example of projection: Lets say foo is a Queryable coming from nhibernate...

```
// Creates anonymous type with one property 'bar'
var list = foo.Select(p => new { p.bar }).ToList();

// Creates a Dto for each element and set property Bar of the Dto.
var list = foo.Select(p => new Dto{ Bar = p.bar }).ToList();
```

Comment: so will using projection only retrieve the data from the DB or is it that all the data is retrieved and the "projection" is done on the returned list?

Comment: Also, I was thinking of using HNibernate to pull the data from a SqlView. So rather than flattening the data with NHibernate I could just do this in SQL. Would this work?

Comment: Nhibernate will generate a SQL statement which retrieves only the data needed, if possible.
You have to try it out any maybe you might have to optimize your mappings. But first of all you have to try to `select` only the columns you need and investigate the query(ies) generated...
And yes you can query views but you would have to map the view separately... I'd do this only if it is really necessary.